# exec() problem with long command in PHP

Tags: php, linux, centos, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf on my server to transfer HTML document to PDF. It works very well when I'm using short URL like :

```
exec("/opt/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf --page-size 'Letter' --orientation 'Portrait' 'http://myurl.com/myPHPfile.php?id=12' '/tmp/myfile.pdf'")
```

The problem occurs when I'm using long command, like :

```
exec("/opt/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf --title 'The name of my file' --page-size 'Letter' --orientation 'Portrait' 'http://myurl.com/myPHPfile.php?phpsid=d8dbfbb91c0748d91426441e67aaf2b6&id=436' '/tmp/The name of my file.pdf'")
```

Note that when I run this long command directly from Putty it works perfectly.

The problem is that when I use exec (or shell_exec() or system() or passthru()) the page keep loading forever and my webserver doesn't respond anymore. I have to close the process from Putty (ps -x and then kill PID) myself.

Note that if I remove the ?phpsid= it works well, which is why I'm saying that the problem only occurs with long command. If I remove ?phpsid=d8dbfbb91c0748d91426441e67aaf2b6 and replace it by ?anything=ImAmAVeryLongStringThatDoNothing it doesn't work too.

I'm on CentOS 5 using WHM/cPanel.
Thanks in advance for any help!

**Edit:**

I tried urlencode(),  doesn't work.
I tried escapeshellarg(), the command is correctly passed but doesn't work.
I tried to use short parameters, the command is correctly passed but doesn't work.

**Edit 2:**

Is there a string length limit while using exec(), system() or passthru()?

**Edit 3:**

Finally, thanks to [Wrikken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358679/wrikken), the problem was that I was passing the session_id() in the URL, and then I was re-using it in the exec(). I had to add session_write_close(); before my exec() so PHP unlocks the current session to make it redable by the script in exec(). See comments below for more informations.

Comment: Is there an unescaped `&` in the url / does it occur with a long url without `&` in it?

Comment: Well....... haha I didn't check that. The problem is that I didn't add urlencode() before passing my URL in exec(). You know when the answer is really simple, right there in our face, but we're searching soooo far. Anyway thanks a lot!!

Comment: Don't use `urlencode`, use [`escapeshellarg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)

Comment: What does `getconf ARG_MAX` output? It's usually seriously in thousands and thousands.

Comment: Well I was wrong it doesn't work, the command no longer make my webserver run in a infinite loop, which is good. Instead, the command just doesn't work. So I removed this escapeshellarg for test, used the short version of the parameters and it does the same. So the problem is not about escaping but really about too long command.

Comment: @Wrikken # getconf ARG_MAX gives 131072

Comment: Can you give us the actual string you are trying to execute? (echo it out, don't guess what it is, there may be another unexpected problem in there).

Comment: Also when I do `echo shell_exec(/opt/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf --page-size Letter --orientation Portrait 'http://sub.mydomain.com/scriptThatOutput.php?phpsid=d8dbfbb91c0748d91426441e67aaf2b6&id=123' '/tmp/Essais de beton du jour (2011-08-04).pdf')`, there is no output, which is weird because wkhtmltopdf actually output some strings while processing.

Comment: I didn't mean the result of the `shell_exec` (I thought you used `exec` by the way, probably doesn't matter here, but they're not the same...), I meant the actual string you are passing. I do seem to see some weird character (`a‌​a``)in that string though, know what that is?

Comment: I was trying `shell_exec`, `exec`, `system`, `passthru`. Anyway, the string I'm passing is `"/opt/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf -s Letter --O $orientation '$url' '$path/$filename'"`. Which weird caracters are you talking about? ( " aa " )?

Comment: @KEvL there are some characters/bytes between those `aa`'s, but that may be a stackoverflow problem.. I get these values between the a's(=97): `97:226:128:140:226:128:139:97`.

Comment: Could you perhaps find a site/location where you echo out the raw `$url` so I can confirm whether those are in there or nor?

Comment: Well if it can help the actual command is `$command = "/opt/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf -s Letter -O $orientation '$url' '$path/$filename'";`, which gives: `/opt/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf -s Letter -O Portrait 'http://website.com/phpscript.php?phpsid=d8dbfbb91c0748d91426441e67aaf2b6&date=2011-08-26' '/tmp/Essais de beton du jour (2011-08-26).pdf'`. This command works great from Putty, but make the webserver enter in an infinite loop (I then have to kill the process)

Comment: Ok so I really don't know why but it seems that the problem come from that line: `if(!empty($_GET['phpsid'])) { session_id(htmlspecialchars($_GET['phpsid'])); } session_start();` I just commented that line and it works........

Comment: Ah, you didn't test the `anything=ImAmAVeryLongStringThatDoNothing` instead of `phpsid` anymore after the escapeshellarg :)

Comment: Oh, BTW: the reason why it 'blocks' is because I assume the session you are trying to open is the same as you are using in the original request itself. If a session is in use by a request, it cannot be opened a second time, and will block until the first request is finished, but that is waiting on the second. You can verify this by calling `session_write_close();` before your `exec`.

Comment: ...... Just ....... wow. Hahahaha thanks soooooo much!!! How could I have even guess that! Seriously thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's update the comment to an answer: **any and all** variable arguments passed to the command line should be escaped with [`escapeshellarg`](http://www.php.net/escapeshellarg)

Answer (score 1):

If the command line is too long, you can use the short version of each parameter. For example, instead of:

```
--page-size 'Letter' --orientation 'Portrait'
```

you can use

```
-s 'Letter' --O 'Portrait'
```