# how do I pass variables from a php page to command line

Tags: php, linux, command-line, wkhtmltopdf

I'm currently using the following two command to generate client statements populated from mysql tables. There are three variables, client_id, date_start. date_end

```
wget -O mypage.html "http://mypage.php?client_id=var1&date_start=var2&date_end=var3"

wkhtmltopdf-i386 --margin-left 5mm --margin-right 5mm mypage.html mypage.pdf
```

This works perfectly and produces usable statements. What I would now like to do is implement a web page using three drop down menus to select each variable rather than directly typing it into linux command line. The user would select the client, date start and date end, using the web interface then click "Print Report". This would send the variables to the command line and run the two lines displayed above.

I know how to make forms but I cant figure out how to pass the variables to the command line and run these 2 lines. I'm sure its simple if anyone can help?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//assumes, you have extracted $clientid, $startdate, $enddate from your $_REQUEST and validated them

$command="wget -O mypage.html \"http://mypage.php?client_id=$clientid&date_start=$startdate2&date_end=$enddate\"";
exec($command, $output, $status);
if ($status!=0) die("wget failed");


$command="htmltopdf-i386 --margin-left 5mm --margin-right 5mm mypage.html mypage";
exec($command, $output, $status);
if ($status!=0) die("htmltopdf failed");
```

Pitfalls: You should use `/path/to/wget` and `/path/to/htmltopdf-i386` to make sure, your PATH is OK

Comment: Thank you,

So if im not mistaken I create a normal HTML drop down form, and the action launches this script?

How do I specify which folder to output the files too?

Many thanks

Comment: it fails at the wget stage it might be because of what you said about the path.

Usually I run the two commands from /home/users/user1/ how do i ensure this is the case here?

Comment: first of all try `$command="wget -O mypage.html 'http://mypage.php?client_id=$clientid&date_start=$startdate2&date_end=$enddate'";`(Just to make sure, single quotes now.

Comment: Okay. Still fails. It must be the file path?

Comment: On the command line run `which wget`, this will give you something like `/usr/bin/wget` - put this int $command instead of wget

Comment: i did an echo of the command to check the variables were passing correctly. They were, and I copied what was echoed directly into the command line and it generated the html file without any problem. it must be the output location?

Comment: Did you add the path to wget? That your shell finds it from the command line is no guarantee, that PHP will find it as well!

Comment: yes I did I changed it in the php and it still generates the error. I'm running out of ideas. I only have permission to run two lines from certain directories. Could it be trying to run the script from a directory i do not have permission to call from? Can i specify which directory I want the script to run from?

Comment: you could try `wget -O /home/users/user1/mypage.html ...`

Comment: Again the echoed command runs perfectly. But not via the PHP script. Its confusing me so much! Thank you for all your help by the way

Comment: Please edit to `if ($status!=0) die("wget failed with status $status");` and post output

Comment: /usr/bin/wget -O /home/users/user1/mypage.html 'http://mypage.php?client_id=SJC&date_start=201201&date_end=201201'wget failed with status Array

Comment: Now that's cool! PHP docs say, the output array is param nr. 2 ($output in my code), and the return value is param Nr. 3 ... whatever: Just comment out the two lines `if ($status!=0) die("...` and see if it works.

Comment: sorry I was wrong originally this is the error "wget failed with status 1" (i took the $output variable out to test something and forgot to put it back in. What does it do anyway? should I be specifying something to it $output=?

Comment: $output contains the output of the command, we don't use it. wget error code 1 is unhelpfull - "generic error" ... does mypage.html get created?

Comment: No it doesnt. Perhaps I am being stupid. I'll send you a message now with the entire source code just to be certain

Comment: '[code]'<?php
$client_id=$_POST["client_id"];
$date_start=$_POST["date_start"];
$date_end=$_POST["date_end"];

$command="/usr/bin/wget -O /home/users/user1/mypage2.html 'http://mypage.php?client_id=$client_id&date_start=$date_start&date_end=$date_end'";
exec($command, $output, $status);
if ($status!=0) die("wget failed with status $status");


$command="/home/users/scorbet/wkhtmltopdf-i386 --margin-left 5mm --margin-right 5mm mypage.html mypagetest.pdf";
exec($command, $output, $status);
if ($status!=0) die("htmltopdf failed");

?>'[code]'

Comment: AHA!!!! Now I get it!!! The webserver doesn't have the privileges to write, but you have! God I am silly! So (in your directory): 1. run `touch mypage2.html` 2. run `chmod 666 mypage2.html` 3. run `chmod 755 /home/users/scorbet/wkhtmltopdf-i386`4. run `touch mypagetest.pdf`5. run `chmod 666 mypagetest.pdf` 6. retry

Comment: Still fails. I think your right about the permissions tho, I cant think of anything else it could be. the problem is I dont want to have to do this everytime I create a file. The files will have dynamic names such as $client_id$date_start.pdf and the possiblities could be limitless

Comment: Can you create the files in a subfolder? You could create the subfolder with chmod 777 and be done with it

Comment: sure let me do that now and retry. Do i have the wkhtmltopdf-i386 in the sub folder as well?

Comment: Would be the best Idea to copy wkhtmltopdf-i386 to the subfolder and chmod 755 it

Comment: Its unbelievable but I still get the same error and the html file is not created :(

Comment: Next: replace the `die(...)` by `{print_r($output); die(...); }` and see, if wget complains about something special

Comment: Array ( ) wget failed with status 1

Comment: So no luck either. OK, remove the first part with wget from the code (we can make it with PHP), manually run the wget, then try the PHP for the htmltopdf

Comment: Fails still. At least its consistant, the pdf is not generated even tho I have created the mypage.html directly via the command line. Its as if all exec scripts are blocked

Comment: ... all exec scripts blocked ... do you have safe mode enabled in php.ini ?

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php is the answer to your needs :)

It even gets the output for you (in case of error messages etc, very usefull)

to run multiple commands use && eg:
    system("ls && exit");

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, when I try to run it from the command line it works like a charm, but, if I try to execute it via browser it doesn't work.

I have even tested with the command line the same piece of code in a test.php file. 
In command line it generates the pdf file but in browser it doesn't.

You have assigned your question as answered. I can't see where is the right answer...

Maybe you are having the same problem solved in this question [exec() problem with long command in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928171/exec-problem-with-long-command-in-php)

Look at Edit 3

Comment: I did it, i had to use the full path found with which wkhtmltopdf in the exec command plus the correct https authentication --username myuser --password mypass